# How to use multiple columns in WHERE clause in SQL Server in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, insert, sqlxml

I am trying to write a SQL/XML query in SQL Server to update a certain row in the database table. I have two tables: the first called edition with columns `id, year, translations, book`.

Example

- id = "17"
- year = "1997"
- translations =

  ```
  <Translations>
       <Translation Language="English" Price="120" />
       <Translation Language="Russian" Price="110" />
  </Translations>
  ```
- book = "11"

The second table called book having the columns: id, title. Example(id = "11" , Title = "Encore une fois")

I have written the following query which so far works fine

```
UPDATE edition
SET translations.modify('insert element Translation {attribute Language 
{"Norwegian"}, attribute Publisher {"KLC"}, attribute Price {200}} as last 
into (/Translations)[1]');
```

But now I want to add conditions to my statement using `WHERE` clause like the following but I keep getting an error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

```
WHERE(book , year) IN (SELECT id, MAX(year) 
                       FROM book AS b, edition AS e
                       WHERE title = 'Encore une  fois'
                         AND b.id = e.book
                       GROUP BY 1)
```

The reason for adding to the condition is to update the latest edition only.
how can i modify the condition to be accepted in SQL Server?

Comment: Your inner select has "id, MAX(year)", but no "group by", so it will fail. Please fix it. Multicolumn IN is not supported in SQL Server, you need to use EXISTS or other similar syntax.

Comment: Please also post definition of your tables and some sample data.

Comment: "SQL Developer"? Are you using Oracle and not SQL Server?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](http://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE edition
SET ...
FROM edition INNER JOIN book ON edition.book = book.id
WHERE title = 'Encore une fois'
AND year IN (SELECT MAX(e2.year)
             FROM edition AS e2
             WHERE e2.book = book.id)
```